# How can I upload file in JavaScript and PHP without using FormData

Tags: javascript, php

I try to make upload page without refresh, when I select the file and press the button it does not come back with the file information if I use value, it gives me `c:/fakepath/filename` or `undefined`. I just want to upload file without using `FormData`.

Here is the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head><script src="http://localhost/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script></head>
 <body>
   <form  enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="up[]" multiple>
     <input type="file" name="up[]">
     <input type="file" name="upload">
   </form>
   <script>
     $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
       event.preventDefault();
     });
     function omg(){
       var elements= $( "form>*" );
       $formdata=new FormData();
       for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
         var element=elements[i];
         var elementtype=element.type;
         var elementname=element.name;
         if(elementtype == "file"){
           if(element.value !== ""){
             var files=element.files;
             alert(files.name);
             $("div").append(element.value + "<BR>");
           }
         }
       }
     }
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>File upload</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form action="fileupload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="myFrame">
     <input type="file" name="up[]" multiple>
     <input type="file" name="up[]">
     <input type="file" name="upload">
     <input type="submit" value="send">
   </form><iframe style="display:hidden" name="myFrame"></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I haven't seen this method for ages :)

Comment: Me neither, but what to do if you do not want to adhere to the current methods